# Meyer curd without added sugar?

Tags: lemon

Is there any reason I can't make a Meyer lemon curd without adding sugar. Is the sugar doing anything structural or is it just taste? Should I adjust the number of eggs?

Comment: Have you ever eaten a lemon?

Comment: @Doug : Meyer lemons are sweeter than other varieties of lemon, and I personally like tart things.  If I had a source of Meyer lemons, I'd be willing to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugar acts as a stabilizer in the heating process of eggs. It acts as a bit of "insurance" to keep the eggs from curdling under the moderate heat during the cooking process. It is a necessary component in making citrus curds.